# How to read device information in Android 10?

Tags: android, android-security, android-10.0, device-instance-id

I am trying to read device Information like Build.SERIAL and DeviceId with TelephonyManager. In Android 9 and below I was able to access all this information without any Issue.

I am receiving following exception when I try to read Device info in **Android 10**

**GetDeviceId: the user 10727 do not meet the requirement to access device identifies.**

This information is very important for my app's security. I need way to identify device with non-changeable device identity.

Comment: Have you got a solution for this(getting unique id)?

Comment: Google will let you read if your app is carrier service provider app .. it has to signed and receive a carrier service provider certification to read device info. My issue was solved when I signed the application.

Answer (score 0):

As stated here it is one of the changes introduced in android 10:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/highlights

You should try to use one of the best practices here:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Anyway, based on my experience, if You are getting a UUID inside Your app, You will get the same uuid even if Your app is uninstalled and reinstalled again. Note, that this uuid is not actual device uuid on newer Android devices. But still, if You store it on your server, it can be usable to detect uninstall and reinstall.

```
Settings.Secure.getString(App.instance.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: I understand Google have block the access to device info in Android 10, is there any way to identify exact device? If UUID keep changing, I won't be able to detect the particular device.

or Is there anyway to be privileged app?